# Conditional Count() in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, where-clause, conditional-statements

How to get the result using formula field in crystalreport 
for counting number of records where fieldname =xxx

like: select count(*) as cnt from tbl where f1=xxx

and explain more with examples for crystal report count() function.

Project: VB.Net
regards,
Sensa.

Answer (score 6):

you basically create a formula field like:

```
if {mytable.field} = 'xxx' then
 {mytable.field};
```

then `count({formula})`;

or use running totals with an evaluation formula: `{mytable.field} = 'xxx'`

Comment: Hi Lee Tickett, thanks for your reply, but its not the direct answer. I like to use crystal report count() function with condition.

Comment: I've tweaked it to use count() instead. But the previous answer was probably better. I'm fairly certain there's no `countif` function in crystal.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

FormulaField1:

```
if {anytable.yourfield} = 'xxx' then 1 Else 0;
```

And then:

FormulaField2:

```
sum({formula1});
```

For integer:

FormulaField2:

```
CSTR (sum({formula1}),0);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several alternatives each with certain drawbacks.

1) Use the select expert to restrict the records in the report conditionally.
The major drawback in this case is of course loss of data probably relevant to other parts of the report

2) Solution 1) using a sub-report integrated in the main report.
The problem in this case is formatting constraints

3) Use grouping. I.E. group by mytable.field use a running total on the records
withing the group and insert to group header. Hide the group selectively trough the section expert.
Here again arises the problem of additional formatting constraints.

4) Finally if you have access to the actual database. Create a view, this will be the best solution in terms of performance and issues with formatting within crystal reports. 
However creating a view each time this kind of problem arises can lead to polluting your database with views which will only be used infrequently.